# Using the same object on different classes while keeping content of one object

Tags: c#, winforms, object, parameters

I am having 3 classes. First class is a Authorize class which have get/set property for User and Pass. Second, Add class is creating new instance of Authorize class and assigning a value from it's textboxes to the properties by using initializing new object:

```
Authorize authorize = new Authorize();
```

Third class, Display, is trying to get the value of property User and Pass from class Authorize. The problem is that I can not use here a new object of Authorize, because it will empty the content of first created object.

```
// Can not do, because the object will be discarded and new one created.
Authorize authorize = new Authorize();
```

How can I avoid/change this so I can access the same object from different class? This is a theoretical example. I am working on code but it's lengthily. If needed, I can post it here. But for now I leave as it is.

Please ask questions if I am not clear enough.

Examples for dummies highly recommended :)

Regards

-- Edit -- Some code:

**AddEntryWindow.sc as Display class**

```
namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    public partial class AddEntryWindow : Form
    {
        private string user, pass;

        // Initializind ArrayList to store all data needed to be added or retrived.
        static private ArrayList addedEntry = new ArrayList();

        // Initializing MainWindow form.
        MainWindow mainWindow;

        // Making authentication possible.
        // AuthenticateUser authenticateUser = new AuthenticateUser();

        EncryptDecrypt en = new EncryptDecrypt();

        // Default constructor to initialize the form.
        public AddEntryWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public AddEntryWindow(MainWindow viaParameter) : this()
        {
            mainWindow = viaParameter;
        }

        public AddEntryWindow(string user, string pass)
        {
            this.user = user;
            this.pass = pass;
        }

        private void btnAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Making sure that type is selected.
            if {}
            else
            {
                // reason why I need the content of AuthenticationUser content.
                string encrypted = en.Encrypt(stringBuilder.ToString(), user, pass);
                string decrypted = en.Decrypt(encrypted, user, pass);

                MessageBox.Show(user + pass);
                    //encrypted + Environment.NewLine + decrypted;

                /*mainWindow.ChangeTextBox = stringBuilder.ToString() + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Encrypted" + Environment.NewLine +
                    encrypted + Environment.NewLine +
                    "Decrypted" + Environment.NewLine +
                    decrypted + Environment.NewLine;
                */
            }
        }

        public static void ShowMe(AuthenticateUser au)
        {
            au.UserName = user;
            au.Password = pass;
        }

        private void cmbType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Deciding which data must be entered depending on
            // what type is selected from combo box.

            // PC
            // Web Site
            // Serial Code
        }
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationWindow.cs as Add class**

```
namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    public partial class AuthenticationWindow : Form
    {
        public AuthenticationWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUserName.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please fill both information first.");
            }
            else
            {
                AuthenticateUser au = new AuthenticateUser();

                au.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
                au.Password = txtPassword.Text;

                AddEntryWindow.ShowMe(au);

                MessageBox.Show(au.UserName + au.Password);

                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Less important AuthenticateUser.cs as Authorize class.**

```
using System;

namespace Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes
{
    public class AuthenticateUser
    {
        private string userName, password;

        public AuthenticateUser()
        {
        }

        public AuthenticateUser(string userNamePassed, string passwordPassed)
        {
            this.userName = userNamePassed;
            this.password = passwordPassed;
        }

        public string UserName
        {
            get
            {
                return userName;
            }
            set
            {
                userName = value;
            }
        }

        public string Password
        {
            get
            {
                return password;
            }
            set
            {
                password = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you pass the existing object itself as param for the Display constructor ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta: Because I might need to reuse the same code in different part of the program. I am trying to keep Authorize class.

Comment: Keep the instance, just get your required values and use them in Display

Comment: @NeedHelper: Using the static method that way doesn't make a lot of sense.  How else are these two windows related?  Does one show the other?  Do they both get shown by some parent window?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: I was trying to try different things. when it's not there i get: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AddEntryWindow.ShowMe(Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AuthenticateUser)' at line: AddEntryWindow.ShowMe(au);

Comment: @NeedHelper: Yeah, but the best way to fix that isn't obvious to me.  That's why I wanted to know how these windows should be related to each other - siblings, or parent/child?  And if parent/child, which is which?  And if siblings, what is their parent?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Well, none of them are related. The only relationship is between other classes. AuthenticateUser is base, AddPC, AddWeb, AddSerial are derived classes.

Comment: Oh, nvm UserInformation is a base class. Not the AuthenticateUser.

Comment: @NeedHelper: I don't mean inheritance.  I mean parent and child **Windows**.  When you click on one window, does it pop the other up?  Or do you click on things on some common parent window to pop both of those up, separately?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: Parent would be the MainWindow. I can display both AddEntryWindow and AuthenticationWindow from it, so they are siblings. Sorry for lack of terminology.

Comment: @NeedHelper: No worries.  Now, how does your logic flow?  Does someone authenticate in the authentication window, then they're able to do other stuff in the main window?  Do they authenticate just once?  Or, how does the logic flow over main window, auth window, and addentry window?  which order, etc.  Just high level info about how you want it to work, not talking about existing code...

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: 1. Start from MainWindow. 2. Authenticate from AuthenticateWindow. 3. Add entry from AddEntryWindow. As I am planning. So login/pass must come from AuthencateWindow to AddEntryWindow so I can use information to encrypt data using login info. I am getting a headache...

Comment: @NeedHelper: Feel free to come back to it tomorrow ;)  I'll edit my answer as best I can to match this flow.

Comment: I would really appreciate it. Thank you so much for trying to help me. I have been stuck on this for over a day with no results.

Comment: @NeedHelper: Alright, updated it.  If you need more clarification you can comment back on my answer again, since I think the question is clear to me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

You've given a bit more clarification in your question, so I'll try to address it.

In the main form, make your code do something like this:

```
private AuthenticateUser storedAuth; // shared data...

private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AuthorizeWindow authWindow = new AuthorizeWindow();
    authWindow.ShowDialog();
    storedAuth = authWindow.Result; // Get the auth result back...
}
```

In the `AuthorizeWindow`, make a result property, and set it when you click OK and have filled in all the data:

```
public AuthenticateUser Result { get; set; }

private void btnAuthenticate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtUserName.Text == string.Empty || txtPassword.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please fill both information first.");
    }
    else
    {
        // Don't try to call the other window here, just set the result and close...
        Result = new AuthenticateUser();
        Result.UserName = txtUserName.Text;
        Result.Password = txtPassword.Text;

        Close();
    }
 }
```

Then on the main form, when you create and open the `AddEntryWindow`, pass it the authentication you stored:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddEntryWindow addWindow =
        new AddEntryWindow(storedAuth.User, storedAuth.Password);
    addWindow.ShowDialog();
}
```

But oops, I've created a small bug here.  We should check if they've authenticated first:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(storedAuth == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You must log in before you add an entry");
    }
    else
    {
        AddEntryWindow addWindow =
            new AddEntryWindow(storedAuth.User, storedAuth.Password);
        addWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Also, I found a small bug in your `AddEntryWindow` code.  Make sure that all the constructors for all your windows always call `InitializeComponent`.  In this case, edit the constructor that takes a username and password to call the default constructor, like your other constructor that takes a `MainWindow` does:

```
public AddEntryWindow(string user, string pass)
    : this() // important!
{
    this.user = user;
    this.pass = pass;
}
```

**Before edit:**

I don't completely understand your example code.  It would be easier if you would create new code samples to add to your question.

Here's what I got from what you've said, though:

```
public class Authorize
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Add
{
    public void Login()
    {
        Authorize authorize = new Authorize();
        authorize.Username = usernameTextBox.Text;
        authorize.Password = passwordTextBox.Text;
        // Todo: Rest of login logic here
    }

    // Todo: Other code here...
}

public class Display
{
    public void Show()
    {
        Authorize authorize = new Authorize();
        // uh oh, Username and Password are null!
    }

    // Todo: Other code here...
}
```

**Solution**

The easiest way to do this is to pass the instance of `Authorize` to the `Show` method (or whatever you are actually calling it) in your `Display` class.  Just accept an instance of `Authorize` as an argument to that method:

```
public class Display
{
    public void Show(Authorize authorize)
    {
        // Now we have the values that the Login method created...
    }

    // ...
}

public class Add
{
    public void Login()
    {
        Authorize authorize = new Authorize();
        authorize.Username = usernameTextBox.Text;
        authorize.Password = passwordTextBox.Text;
        display.Show(authorize);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Ok I see that you are saying. Bu I do have one problem. I can not actually call display.show(authorize) because I am opening Add from Display form. As of right now I am getting error: Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AuthenticateUser' is less accessible than method 'Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AddEntryWindow.Show(Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AuthenticateUser)'. Probably because I do not use 'display.Show(authorize);'.

Comment: With Show() method I am getting: Error 1 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AddEntryWindow.ShowMe(Store_Passwords_and_Serial_Codes.AuthenticateUser)'.

Comment: @NeedHelper: You'll need to post some real code for us to help you farther.  Strip it down how you must, but try to keep these bits of logic and the class's relationships to each other intact.

Comment: Could my problem lay on poor project design?

Comment: I love you dude! Works perfectly!

Comment: @NeedHelper: Glad I could help :)  Cheers!  (remember to click the the check mark called "accept", on the left there)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve what you are looking for.  The first is to just pass a single instance of Authority around to all the different methods that will use it.  I assume this is prohibitive for some reason, otherwise you would already be doing it.  There is a design pattern called [singletons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) that may be useful for what you're doing.  The linked page has some code examples.

Answer (score 0):

Passing as Argument is the best solution, if you have problem in passing as argument,then go for Authorize as Property(Set/Get), so you can get rid out of Argument passing issue. If that is also problem then go either either with Singleton Pattern or create Static class.