# Using ArrayList from different class with out creating new instance of the class

Tags: c#, arraylist, parameter-passing

I had similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004922/using-the-same-object-on-different-classes-while-keeping-content-of-one-object) few days earlier but now is more complicated.

I am trying to use ArrayList from form 2, in form 1. I can not create a new instance of form 2 because it will make my content of form 2 null. How could I do this by changing my piece of code?

Examples for dummies recommended.

**Edit**

```
        int totalEntries = 0;

        var myarr = SharedResources.Instance.ArrayList;


        if(cmbType.SelectedIndex == 0)
            myarr.Add(new AddPC(cmbType.Text, 
                txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text));
```

Why would above code cause nullreferenceexception?

```
private void sfdSaveToLocation_FileOk(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    EncryptDecrypt en = new EncryptDecrypt();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    // I need the arraylist here but I can not access it as it is.
    foreach (var list in addWindow.addedEntry)
    {
        if (list is AddPC)
        {
            AddPC tmp = (AddPC)list;
            sb.Append(tmp.ToString());
        }
        else if (list is AddWebSite)
        {
            AddWebSite tmp = (AddWebSite)list;
            sb.Append(tmp.ToString());
        }
        else if (list is AddSerialCode)
        {
            AddSerialCode tmp = (AddSerialCode)list;
            sb.Append(tmp.ToString());
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllText(sfdSaveFile.FileName, sb.ToString());
}
```

I already have new instance of AddEntryWindow form here:

```
private void tsmiAddEntry_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (storedAuth == null)
            {
                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show
                    ("You must log in before you add an entry." 
                    + Environment.NewLine + "You want to authenticate?",
                    "Information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                    MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    AuthenticationWindow authWindow =
                        new AuthenticationWindow();
                    authWindow.ShowDialog();
                    storedAuth = authWindow.Result;

                    AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                        (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
                    addWindow.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                AddEntryWindow addWindow = new AddEntryWindow
                    (this, storedAuth.UserName, storedAuth.Password);
                addWindow.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
```

Regards.

Comment: Why are you using `ArrayList`? Unless you're stuck using .NET 1.1, you should be using one of the generic collections.

Comment: @John Saunders: By using List<T> will fix my problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea can be  creating third singletone class that only can have one instance of 
array list and shares it so every class in your app can use it

```
public class ShareArray
{
    private System.Collections.ArrayList arrayList;

    #region Property
    public System.Collections.ArrayList ArrayList { get{return  arrayList;}}
    #endregion

    #region Imp. signletone
    private static ShareArray instance;
    public static ShareArray Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new ShareArray();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }


    private ShareArray()
    {
        arrayList = new System.Collections.ArrayList();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and use this class every where  you want in this way

```
    ShareArray.Instance.ArrayList.Add(value);
```

or

```
var myarr = ShareArray.Instance.ArrayList;
```

Comment: I have seen people talking about singleton, but I didn't fully understand how it works. Great example! I will take a look at it.

Comment: The base Idea is to have only one instace of a class in Application also I recoomend to study about DesignPatterns http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx

Comment: I have some exception thrown. Can you please check out my edit?

Comment: change     public static ShareArray instance; 
to         private static ShareArray instance;

Comment: oh sorry  change         public System.Collections.ArrayList ArrayList { get; set; }
 to         public System.Collections.ArrayList ArrayList { get { return arrayList; } }

Comment: Works like a charm! Only if someone would post such example in my previous 3 questions lol. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing. Such technique could be used to share for example variables?

Answer (score -1):

One solution is array list define as `Static`. but this isn't `Good Choose`.

Describe better your program design! Is form 1 open form 2?